# Access custom base url property from Assemble's options object in partial context

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, assemble

So it seems quite simple (yet I cannot make it work)..

I would like to set a custom property in the options object in Assemble within my Gruntfile and would like to access it from one of my partials context in YML.

So say I have a folder in my project with all my documentation in .md-files.. (app/src/documentation)

In the options object I would like to do something like:

```
assemble: {
      options: {
        jsDoc: '<%= yeoman.app %>/src/documentation',
      },
```

And then within one of my partials I would like to do the following:

```
---
title: Headings
status: In progress
tabs:
  - tab: html
  - tab: css
  - tab: js
  - tab: description
  - tab: links
jsDoc: filename.md
---
<!-- Show markdown documentation -->
{{md jsDoc}}
```

Right now I get an error saying :

```
Warning: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined Use --force to continue.
```

Can anyone give any hints/ideas on how to get this to work?

Bonus info:
To make things a little more complicated, I would actually like to use {{md jsDoc}} in another partial (using my custom helper), where I have access to my other partials context..

I've made a couple of gists showing the code I have right now.

It's located here:

https://gist.github.com/dgsunesen

- **"sgComponent helper"** - showing how i use my helper
- **"Gruntfile"** - showing my current options for my custom helper.
- **"Headings"** - partial that needs to access jsDoc option and get rendered inside of sgComponent.hbs
- **"sgComponent.js"** - my custom helper that takes the base partial and the partial to be render inside of it
- **sgComponent.hbs** - my base partial where my Headings-partial is rendered within.

Thanks in advance!
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only using the partial matter inside it's own partial, then it's pretty simple...

```
---
title: Headings
status: In progress
tabs:
  - tab: html
  - tab: css
  - tab: js
  - tab: description
  - tab: links
jsDoc: "<%= jsDoc %>/filename.md"
---
<!-- Show markdown documentation -->
{{md headings.jsDoc}}
```

You can use lodash templates to combine the main `jsDoc` property with the one in the partial. Then reference based on the name of the partial `{{headings.jsDoc}}`

But from looking at your helper code, it looks like you want `jsDoc` to be set inside another partial (that's dynamically added), then used inside the `sgComponent` file.
To do that, I think instead of doing the process content you'll need to actually combine the variables from the main options with the `jsDoc` in the partial. If you try doing process content with the lodash, it'll get into a loop because of how you're getting the front matter in the helper.

Also, make sure parameters are being passed in properly because that `indexof` error could be coming from `glob` or `yfm`.

Hope this helps some.

Comment: Hi doowb.. I've tried what you suggested above, but it's like my assembling tasks are stalling.. :-/

Comment: Can you maybe give an example of what you mentioned? Much appreaciated :)

Comment: @dgsunesen checkout this repo https://github.com/doowb/assemble-support-partial-context I changed `jsDoc` to `jsDocBase` in the assemble options, then use the base inside the partials: `jsDoc: <%= jsDocBase %>/filenamem.md`. Then I had to add parent selectors in the handlebars file so you get to the correct context. You'll see that in the sgComponent.hbs file.